# Determine conversation quality

Tags: python, speech, cmusphinx

Theoretically, a stimulating/lively conversation between two speakers has a) ~50/50 split between speakers and b) high words per minute (WPM) exchange. This will then get processed and sent to arduino which will have a light display per conversation quality.

Should I use CMU Sphinx with Python? All the speech recognition tutorials/examples I've seen are just too sophisticated.

I don't need a library to decipher words or a translator. Any thoughts on open source options?

Comment: You can you cmusphinx, as for the question you need to be more precise on the problems you have.